# write GET URL variable to page using javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, encoding, get

I have a form which contains a wysiwyg editor. The form data is sent to a page using a GET method in the form.

How would i decode(to keep the DIV and BR tags) in the variable and print it out on the page using Javascript?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Don't [inject markup from the URL into the page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) without running it through an HTML parser that checks every element and attribute against a white list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent of decode would be unescape(), you should be able to something like this:

```
(function(){ 
   document.$_GET = [];
   var urlHalves = String(document.location).split('?');
   if(urlHalves[1]){
      var urlVars = urlHalves[1].split('&');
      for(var i=0; i<=(urlVars.length); i++){
         if(urlVars[i]){
            var urlVarPair = urlVars[i].split('=');
            document.$_GET[urlVarPair[0]] = urlVarPair[1];
         }
      }
   }
})();

document.write(unescape(document.$_GET['varname']));
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try this script: http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-url-decode-encode.html
It encodes decodes everything.